# V4l2 : difference between : Enque, Deque and Queue(ing) of the buffer?

Tags: android-camera, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, v4l2

I am a noob in **v4l2** and tryign to find out the difference between the various `ioctl` calls made during the camera image capture. I am following [this pdf](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/presentations/summit_jun_2010/20100206-fosdem.pdf) from the linuxtv.org site 
I wanted to know the difference between the following :

**Query, Enque, Deque and Queue(ing)** of the buffer. Is there a particular sequence in fetching the raw data from the camera? Does the sequence varies in case of streaming and capture mode?

Can any one plz explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following state machine describes a V4L2-buffer's life-cycle:

[image]

The sequence is the same for both streaming as well as capture.
Its just that during capture one does the Q/DQ just once to obtain one buffer (i.e. a single "frame"). Streaming does this repeatedly.

Detailed info in this series of V4L2 articles...
[**Part 1: The Video4Linux2 API**](http://lwn.net/Articles/203924/)
**[Part 2: registration and open()](http://lwn.net/Articles/204545/)**
**[Part 3: Basic ioctl() handling](http://lwn.net/Articles/206765/)**
**[Part 4: Inputs and Outputs](http://lwn.net/Articles/213798/)**
**[Part 5a: Colors and formats](http://lwn.net/Articles/218798/)**
**[Part 5b: Format negotiation](http://lwn.net/Articles/227533/)**
**[Part 6a: Basic frame I/O](http://lwn.net/Articles/235023/)**
**[Part 6b: Streaming I/O](http://lwn.net/Articles/240667/)**
**[Part 7: Controls](http://lwn.net/Articles/247126/)**